# Migrate from one Graph Database to another

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, rdf, rdfs

**How can you migrate your data from one graph database (Neo4j, Tiger Graph etc.) to another?**

Background:
I have to decide between the standards of the W3C (RDF (S), OWL) and
Databases for property graphs (Neo4j, TigerGraph etc.).
I know that all "triple stores" that support the W3C standard also make it possible to simply "pull out" the data
and import it into another triple store.
For relational databases there is also the standard SQL (and dialects),
so that with a little effort you can get the data from one relational database to another.
But I can't think of such a solution for graph databases.

Comment: right. Because there is no such standard. I mean, property graph vs RDF is totally different. I think you have to convert the exported data to the import data - if possible. But as long as there is no such standard (GQL will be the SQL for graphs, but it takes some more years)

Answer (score 1):

As someone already mentioned for the property graphs there is no defined standard as of now. There are efforts going to build such standards called GQL https://www.gqlstandards.org/

However, for importing data from RDF to property graphs. Tigergraph and neo4j provides option to load your rdf data to the respective platforms. This might not provide complete switch over capabilities from RDF to Property graph but can help with solutions for certain scenarios.

For interchanging data between property graphs you might have to re-create schema when you switch platforms. For data loading most of property graph dbs provide option to load using csv's.